# Mpmovieplayercontroller video pause while clicking button for another functionality

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, mpmovieplayercontroller

i am using `MPMovieplayerController` for playing video, while im clicking some other button i.e i want to pause my video wherever its playing again. i click play means i want to play while its pausing.But for me now when i click  button means my video was stopped.But i want to pause instead of stop.
    My sample code here

```
    - (IBAction) playvideo
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://xyz/video1.mp4"];
    movieplayer = [[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:url] retain]; 
movieplayer.view.frame=CGRectMake(25,54,658,460);    
    [self.view addSubview:movieplayer.view];
    [movieplayer play];
}

-(void)buttononclick
{

    [movieplayer pause];
    [movieplayer.view removeFromSuperview];

    for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++)
    {
CGRect frame;
frame.origin.x = 150 * i;
frame.origin.y = 0;
frame.size = CGSizeMake(140, self.scrollView.frame.size.height);
        [scrollView setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];



        UIImageView *temp1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25, 7, 75, 75)];
        [temp1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sti15.png"]];
        [self.scrollView addSubview:temp1];


        UIImageView *temp2 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(110, 7, 75, 75)];
        [temp2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sti16.png"]];
        [self.scrollView addSubview:temp2];


        UIImageView *temp3 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(195, 7, 75, 75)];
        [temp3 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sti17.png"]];
        [self.scrollView addSubview:temp3];

}
    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(165 * 10, self.scrollView.frame.size.height);
    self.scrollView.pagingEnabled=0;
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
   // [self setDescText:nil];
[super viewDidDisappear:animated];
    [movieplayer pause];
    [movieplayer.view removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Comment: can u tell the way to pause video

Answer (score 3):

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if ((movie.playbackState==MPMoviePlaybackStateStopped)||(movie.playbackState==MPMoviePlaybackStatePaused)) 
    {
        [movie play];  
    }
    else
    {
        [movie pause];
    }
}
```

Try this Code , it will Work

Answer (score 0):

Check out the notifications for `MPMoviePlaybackStatePlaying`, `MPMoviePlaybackStateStopped`, `MPMoviePlaybackStatePaused`, and `MPMoviePlaybackStateInterrupted`.

Something like:

```
MPMoviePlayerController *player = notification.object;
/* Playback is currently stopped. */
    if (player.playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackStateStopped)
    {
        NSLog(@"MPMoviePlaybackStateStopped");
    }

/*  Playback is currently under way. */
    else if (player.playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackStatePlaying)
    {        
        NSLog(@"MPMoviePlaybackStatePlaying");
        }

/* Playback is currently paused. */
    else if (player.playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackStatePaused)
    {
        NSLog(@"MPMoviePlaybackStatePaused");
    }
```

You can wire up your target action something like this:

```
if ((_moviePlayer.playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackStateStopped) || (_moviePlayer.playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackStatePaused)) {
            [_moviePlayer play];
        } else {
            [_moviePlayer pause];
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add target to the play/pause button.
but first you need to catch the button of the mpmovieplayerview.

step 1 list the button. method reference from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7243888/how-to-list-out-all-the-subviews-in-a-uiviewcontroller-in-ios)

call this method from when the button appear(the video is ready). 
But remember, this will also catch the full screen button and airplay button.(if available)

```
- (void)CatchSubviewsOfView:(UIView *)view {

// Get the subviews of the view
NSArray *subviews = [view subviews];

for (UIView *subview in subviews) {

    // Do what you want to do with the subview
    NSLog(@"%@", subview);
    if(subview isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]){
        // add your target here
        [subview addTarget:self action:@selector(extraAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }

    // List the subviews of subview
    [self listSubviewsOfView:subview];
}
}
```

step 2 implement the action

```
-(IBAction)extraAction:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"some extraAction");
}
```

call the catch method sample.
    [self CatchSubviewOfView:movieplayer.view];