# ios how can get the list of subview on view?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, subview

Any of you knows how can I can get the list of subviews on view?. there is a way to get the list into in array?

```
NSMutableArray *subviews= .... //all my subviews
```

Comment: You should read the manual... [UIView Class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW17) has the answer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do in this way

```
- (void)listSubviewsOfView:(UIView *)view {

    // Get the subviews of the view
    NSArray *subviews = [view subviews];

    // Return if there are no subviews
    if ([subviews count] == 0) return;

    for (UIView *subview in subviews) {

        NSLog(@"%@", subview);

        // List the subviews of subview
        [self listSubviewsOfView:subview];
    }
}
```

Please go through this link [How to list out all the subviews in a uiviewcontroller in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7243888/how-to-list-out-all-the-subviews-in-a-uiviewcontroller-in-ios)