# Setting adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth globally for all UILabels

Tags: ios, objective-c

We have a multilingual app in which the size of text in labels can change depending on the language in use. e.g. German uses more space than English in a lot of spaces. In such cases, iOS automatically shrinks the text, substituting the middle letters with ".."

e.g. Cancel becomes Ca..el

It's easy to fix these cases individually by setting the `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` to YES in the label. But it's laborious to do so for every single label out there.

Is there a way one could set it to YES globally for all `UILabel` instances in the app? I tried using UIAppearance but it seems that it does not support the `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` property.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can add the below code at ViewDidLoad for each ViewController of app:

```
NSArray *allSub = [self.view subviews];
for (id sub in allSub) {

    if ([sub isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
        UILabel *lb =sub;
        lb.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice. But I expect that you'd have to do a recursive descent, in case there are UILabels within other subviews.

Comment: Yes. Thanks because your idea. We can refer this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7243888/how-to-list-out-all-the-subviews-in-a-uiviewcontroller-in-ios)

Answer (score 1):

I think more cleaner way is to do a category for UILabel like this:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UILabel (FR)

@property(nonatomic) UIBaselineAdjustment baselineAdjustment;
@property(nonatomic) CGFloat minimumScaleFactor;

@end
```

.

```
#import "UILabel+FR.h"

@implementation UILabel (FR)

#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wobjc-protocol-method-implementation"

- (void)didMoveToSuperview {
    self.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
    self.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5;

    [super didMoveToSuperview];
}

#pragma clang diagnostic pop

@end
```

And include it in your Prefix.h file