# How to hide the Undo and Redo bar button items in the Keyboard's Shortcut bar?

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard

I would like to hide the Undo and Redo bar button items in the Keyboard's Shortcut bar (available in iOS 9+). I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32670035/ios-9-ipad-keyboard-get-rid-of-undo-view) that you can hide them by using this code. Unfortunately this hides also the Cut and Copy items which rather I prefer to keep.

```
let item : UITextInputAssistantItem = yourTextView.inputAssistantItem
item.leadingBarButtonGroups = [] // this hides Undo, Redo and also Cut, Copy and Paste
```

Comment: "Cut" and "Copy" can still be used the old-fashioned way, by long-pressing on a valid field. With that, wouldn't removing the shortcut bar be a good idea?

Comment: Thank you for the comment huniserd_suraj, in fact, it might make sense