# UITextField inputView displays undo, redo, paste buttons

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, inputview

I have created a custom `inputView` for my `UITextField`. The view itself looks and functions great, but on the iPad I'm getting undo, redo, and paste buttons above my custom `inputView`. How do I remove those buttons? They don't have any functionality, but they should be removed.

[image]

Answer (score 31):

With Swift 3 and XCode 8 I was able to remove the bar by removing the two button groups on the text field input:

```
self.textField.inputAssistantItem.leadingBarButtonGroups.removeAll()
self.textField.inputAssistantItem.trailingBarButtonGroups.removeAll()
```

Answer (score 7):

```
// hide undo, redo, paste button bar for textfield input view
UITextInputAssistantItem* item = [your_textfield inputAssistantItem];
item.leadingBarButtonGroups = @[];
item.trailingBarButtonGroups = @[];
```

will hide the top bar for input view.

Reference:[How to hide the shortcut bar in iOS9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32606655/how-to-hide-the-shortcut-bar-in-ios9)

Answer (score -3):

Try removing the `inputAccessoryView`:

```
self.textField.inputAccessoryView = nil;
```

Comment: That didn't work but did help lead me in the correct direction. Instead of using `inputAccessoryView`, I needed to modify the `inputAssistantItem`. This SO post was very helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32606655/how-to-hide-the-shortcut-bar-in-ios9

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing with a picker - but InputAssistantItem is read only...?