# What is below the DatePicker ToolBar and How Do I Hide It

Tags: ios, swift, datepicker

What are these arrow and clipboard icons that show up along with a UIDatepicker below the toolbar called? They do not do anything when tapped.

How can I programmatically hide them?

[image]

Comment: What device and iOS version are you on?

Comment: This is an iPad Pro (12.9 inch) 4th generation emulator screenshot running 14.0. This may only show up on iPads, but I am not 100% sure.

Comment: SwiftUI or UIKit? Title says DatePicker, but question says UIDatePicker...

Comment: UIKit but it is not clear to me why that would matter

Comment: It matters because I haven't been able to reproduce this. I'm getting an entirely different layout for my date pickers. You're going to have to post some code, because I  think this depends on what context the UIDatePicker is in. Is it embedded in something else?

Comment: Ah brilliant, thank you! It is indeed embedded in a TextField, so it is the TextField that is causing it. This covers it:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33487914/uitextfield-inputview-displays-undo-redo-paste-buttons