# in ios9, when editing the UITextField there has a "gray toolbar" appear at bottom

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9, ios9.1

i found one issue found on ios9 , when i editing on the UITextField there has a "gray toolbar" appear at bottom, only found this issue on ios9.

Appreciate if you can help.
Many thanks

screen shot as below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHNUU.jpg)

---

Fixed:
as i use the wrong keyword to search, when i change the keyword and search again and found out the solution at : [How to hide the shortcut bar in iOS9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32606655/how-to-hide-the-shortcut-bar-in-ios9)

Thanks

Comment: Means when u click on Textfield toolbar became gray ?

Comment: is it showing in Simulator ??? Did you tried in Device ??

Comment: @RushangPrajapati  i mean when i click the textfield, a gray toolbar auto appear at the bottom on the screen, only found on ios9.

Comment: @AshishMathur Yes, also the same problem in Device.

Comment: Then you can hide toolbar on text field edit also make break point there check it i am sure its little mistakes