# How can I hide quicktype keyboard toolbar on iPad?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, keyboard

How can I hide quicktype keyboard toolbar on iPad?

[image]

The following code doesn't work:

```
textField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

place this code in **viewDidLoad**

```
yourTextFieldName.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
UITextInputAssistantItem* shortcut = [yourTextFieldName inputAssistantItem];
shortcut.leadingBarButtonGroups = @[];
shortcut.trailingBarButtonGroups = @[];
```

**Swift**

```
    yourTextFieldName.autocorrectionType = .No
    let shortcut : UITextInputAssistantItem = yourTextFieldName.inputAssistantItem
    shortcut.leadingBarButtonGroups = []
    shortcut.trailingBarButtonGroups = []
```

**swift3**

```
 yourTextFieldName.autocorrectionType = .no
 var shortcut: UITextInputAssistantItem? =     yourTextFieldName.inputAssistantItem()
shortcut?.leadingBarButtonGroups = []
shortcut?.trailingBarButtonGroups = []
```

for [reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextInputAssistantItem_class/)

Answer (score 1):

[How to hide the shortcut bar in iOS9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32606655/how-to-hide-the-shortcut-bar-in-ios9)

Have you tried this yet? What you do is simply disable the text proposals, not the undo / redo / paste ... thingies.

Answer (score 0):

> To hide shortcuts altogether, set the leadingBarButtonGroups and trailingBarButtonGroups properties to nil. Doing so hides only the shortcuts and does not hide the typing suggestions. To hide typing suggestions, you must also set the autocorrectionType property of the responder that displays the keyboard to UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo.

```
<editorView>.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
UITextInputAssistantItem* shortcut = [<editorView> inputAssistantItem];
shortcut.leadingBarButtonGroups = @[];
shortcut.trailingBarButtonGroups = @[];
```