# Xamarin Forms (iOS) - Remove Shortcut Bar from Picker

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, picker

In Xamarin Forms, here's the default iOS Picker:

[image]

How do I remove the shortcut bar (undo / redo / copy / paste)?

[image]

Comment: Is that from a simulator? What version of iOS? Looking on the iPad 2 iOS 8.1 simulator, my default Xamarin Forms `Picker` does not show that shortcut bar.

Comment: Yes, it's a simulator - iPad 2 / iOS 9.3

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your custom renderer, you simply need to set the Control's `InputAssistantItem.LeadingBarButtonGroups` and `InputAssistantItem.TrailingBarButtonGroups` to `null`.

The renderer would look something like this:

[image]